# multiple indexer access to incomplete data

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

If there are multiple indexer from redis access to data, resulting in each indexer data are not complete, I would like to ask how to solve this problem? Generally speaking, a logstash system can only be one indexer?
So if there are multiple indexer how to ensure that each indexer can get the complete data?

Comment: Your question is unclear, please rephrase. And make sure there is only one question, clearly asked.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood was that you're trying to create multiple indexes using `logstash` where you're pulling up data from `Redis`. I haven't worked with redis but then, I could tell you that `logstash` also can handle in creating multiple indexes.

You can either do create the indexes within the same `logstash` configuration file, where you might have if conditions in order to maybe separate your incoming data to the appropriate indexes or else you could have different `logstash` configuration files as much as you need.

You might have a look at [this](http://logz.io/blog/5-logstash-pitfalls-and-how-to-avoid-them/) for your uncertainty on getting all your data up to ES through `Logstash`.